# How to get error highlighting to show up near scroll bar in VS 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

In Eclipse if there is a warning there is a yellow box by the scroll bar at the point of the warning. The same goes for errors except with a red box.

### Is there any way to accomplish this in VS 2010?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use productivity power tools for VS2010. You can find more info here: [Advanced Scrolling](http://community.dotnetwork.it/AlbertoEng/archive/2011/03/26/vs-2010-productivity-power-tools-advanced-scrolling.aspx), I also use VSCommands2010, lots of useful tools there as well. You can download both from the VS2010 extension gallery inside your VS2010 in Tools>Extension Manager or download the .visx file from the online gallery here:

[VsCommands](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d491911d-97f3-4cf6-87b0-6a2882120acf)

[Productivity power tools(Advanced Scrolling)](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef)